# nodeType == 3 in p elements greater than 150 characters

Tags: jquery

right now, I have this code:

```
var source = $('p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().length > 300;})
    .parent().slice(0,1);
```

By filtering through p elements, I find the first one that is longer than 300 characters, and store the parent of that in source. My question is ...how would I only get text content (typeNode 3). I know this might be a stupid question but trying this.typeNode == 3 doesn't seem to work

The answer below seems to work in some cases, for more clarity, Im putting a border around all the "p" children of the "source". Sometimes, the "p" element contains an image and no text. I tried using the answer below for that and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will only get element nodes. To get all nodes including text nodes, call [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). And switch the words in typeNode to [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) :)

```
var textNodes = $('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.length > 150;
});
```

Comment: well im trying to get the parent() of the first p element which has more than 150 nodeType 3 characters slice(0,1). For test purposes, I tried to put a border the p elements that are the children of this parent().

Comment: @Praneet - I'm not sure I'm getting you. Could you post a sample on http://jsfiddle.net that I can see?

Comment: Oh that won't work, we can't set css on a text node. It only works on elements. I have updated to set the css borer on parents of the text nodes only. Check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/Cza8p/4/. Updated the example as I understand your question better now.